# Changes are not reflected after GWT compile

Tags: tomcat, server, gwt, client-server, development-environment

I am running a GWT application on a tomcat server. Changes in the code on the client side are not reflected even after GWT Compile. I have to restart Eclipse to see the changes. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

When you make changes on the client-side, you could see that immediately if you were using GWT's Hosted mode, as you probably know... To see the changes in Tomcat, you have to re-compile the application AND re-deploy to Tomcat. If you just use the same Jetty server GWT provides for hosting, you can simply re-compile and then re-start the Jetty server, and run your app without including the hosted mode URL parameter `(?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997)`.

As you say you have to restart Eclipse to see the changes, I gather you are using the Tomcat server from within Eclipse... I don't do that, I just run an independent Tomcat server.... Tomcat allows you to do a hot deploy (ie. you can undeploy and then deploy your app again without re-starting the server), which is made easy by the use of the Tomcat Manager (a web app which is shipped with Tomcat by default).... try to use the Tomcat Manager or find out how to do a hot deploy inside Eclipse.